# Emacs transparency with kde4?

Tags: linux, emacs, kde-4

Is there any way to make Emacs partially transparent in kde4? I tried some of the solutions proposed online, but none of them had any effect at all; I suspect it might be an issue with kde, but I am not actually sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the application-specific KWin settings for Emacs?  If you right-click the title-bar of Emacs, and select Advanced->Special Application Settings, you should get app-specific settings which will be used whenever Emacs opens.  I selected "Active Opacity %" in the "Preferences" tab, set it to 75, and selected "Force" in the drop-down.  Emacs now comes up with 75% opacity whenever it launches.

Note: I'm using KDE 4.4.

---

**Edit:**
Just for reference: a brief search for Emacs + transparency came up with [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs#toc1).  I didn't have any luck with Emacs' settings either.

Comment: That works--I didn't even think of doing it that way.

Comment: That said, a way of doing it from emacs so that I can control it through emacs would be nicer, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: @Tikhon, agreed, but I wonder how much control Emacs may assert over the actual window itself. I would expect that to be solely under the control of KDE, though I may be wrong :^)